# Sum of different values on the same row in a table

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with numbers from 0-5, under different field names (Score1, Score2 etc. all the way to Score50) that need to be summed at the last column of that same row. Each row represents a different client with its own info.

Is it possible and if it is, some help would be nice.

Comment: Unless Access has a limitation on the number of columns you can `+` together in the query, I don't see a real problem here - except your data layout: you should normalize your table a bit more, with a column for "client_id" and only one score per row.

Comment: The problem is Access wont let me calculate the sum of values in the same row. Was just wondering if thats possible at all. I'm pretty new to Access so I don't know how to mark new Clients with their own ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, Score1 + Score2 + ... + Score50 as TotalScore
from table
```

You can fill in the rest of the scores :-)

By the way, you really should normalise this table. It will make your life much easier.

Comment: Sure I could and would if I had any idea how :D I'm just pretty new to this Access stuff still.

Comment: No worries, but did my query above work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with same Query Defined by Yawar
select *, Score1 + Score2 + ... + Score50 as Total Score
from table**strong text**

and you do not need to write same query again and again.

Regards,
Sam